# How to prepare section wise dashboard in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to prepare a dashboard exactly like below (with revenue, cost and profit sections and with sub-totals and totals)

But don't know what are the functions to be used.

I have all the underlying data set or data table components.

Can anyone please help?

[image]

Comment: please provide reproducible example with sample data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello @Anitha, such "table" view can be achieved with `gt` package, which lets you format a data frame into a nice table. This is the url where you can learn more about it: https://gt.rstudio.com

Comment: Thanks Manu for your suggestion. I used GT package and it works (though it is very slow in refreshing the contents)